# How to add 2 attachment coloumns in single custom list sp2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, attachment

How to add 2 attachment coloumns in single custom list Sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

You can attach multiple files to OOTB SharePoint custom list using that icon on the ribbon. But you have to enable attachments on the list's advanced settings `List Settings >> Advanced Settings (under General Settings category)`.

These attachments will be shown in one column and you have to view the item to see attached files.